# Correntropy between input and output

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, theano

As part of work to university, I have to implement a training procedure which, fundamentally, trains layer-by-layer an MLP based on the measure of correntropy between the input and output of a given layer.

I have sucessfully found some pieces of code related to correntropy in https://github.com/pdoren/DeepEnsemble/blob/master/deepensemble/utils/utils_functions.py#L238-L264 and https://github.com/pdoren/DeepEnsemble/blob/master/deepensemble/utils/cost_functions.py#L210-L237. However, it is only possible to use this code if the samples have the same size.

So, my question is: how can I compute the correntropy between the input and output of an MLP layer in Theano?

Comment: I don't understand why do you want to do cross entropy between the input and the output and not between the output and the ground truth

Comment: I think you're doing an autoencoder and not a MLP. That's the only explanation I find to compute the correntropy between input and output.

Comment: T.sum(T.mean(T.exp(x**2/sigma), axis=0)) / T.sqrt(2*np.pi*sigma), where x = input-output.

Answer (score 2):

(1) Correntropy is not the same as cross entropy. It has desirable properties of MSE or cross-ent locally, but globally has L1/0 properties in regularizing outliers proportionally with respect to their distance. (2) The follow-up questioner is correct that you don't compute your error metric on input-to-output, but rather output-to-actual (how "far" is prediction from ground truth).

Keras allows for creating your own objective functions / distance metrics. I haven't implemented these yet but found these when I went looking for code using correntropy as objective function in keras:

https://github.com/EderSantana/seya/blob/master/seya/regularizers.py

https://github.com/EderSantana/seya/blob/master/seya/objectives.py

Comment: FYI: Questions and answers on this site should actually have code examples that are completely understandable without needing to reference external links.